# Check for specific configuration in C++ peojects for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, configuration

Is there any way to check for user defined configurations (that is NOT the standard DEBUG or RELEASEones) within C++ code itself, such as a defined variable that matches the configuration name? VS 2010...

I direly need this for an old project where no kind of unit testing is available at all, and where I want to add a few lines (functions, includes, ...) whenever a specific "Debug_Test" configuration is chosen to at least offer very basic unit testing opportunities.

I already read this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913006/ifdef-configuration-in-visual-studio

but I also need to add a few functions for the specific configuration, not just include files for the chosen build.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MSBuild you can do this.

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup><ClCompile>
    <PreprocessorDefinitions>$(Configuration);%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
</ClCompile></ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

then for a configuration called Debug_Test

```
#ifdef Debug_Test
```

Comment: Hoi and thanks for the reply. I am not using a build command, I am ordinarily comiling/building from within VS...

Comment: What's your point? VS will use the msbuild code. Just paste what I gave you in the vcxproj

Comment: Ah, I ill try that. Sorry for not knowing, did not know where to put the lines (linux like envs. offer the (c)makefiles...). Brb

Comment: just before the </Project> at the end

Comment: I put it just before the first ItemDefinitionGroup element I found, it works perfectly. Thanks a lot! Upvote and  answer check following immediately.